# Chrome Dev Tools: Tells me what type of event is attached to element but which file?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome when I right click on a DOM element to see which event listeners are attached it always says jquery.min.js:2 . However, I would like to know which of my JavaScript files contains that listener (e.g. click event listener).

For example, which file has this code in it?

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function(e){ //clicked});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has no way of knowing that.

When you write `$(...).click(function)`, the event handler that gets added to the function is always within jQuery.
Chrome cannot know what callback the jQuery event handler will eventually run.

Comment: Let's say you were a new developer on the project. How would you find the callback?

Comment: I would look in each file and try to find instances of ready bindings. Unless the button is added dynamically then it would have to be bound in a ready function. $(function(){...}) or $(document).ready(function(){...});

Answer (score 0):

If you use addEventListener (instead of $(...).click() ) then Chrome Dev Tools will show you the line in your file where that handler was added.