# How to get event listener of element set through Jquery in chrome dev tool?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery

I tried to search but not found exact solution.

If a div element has onclick event listener set by jquery than how to get value/function triggered on click in chrome dev tool?

I try in dev tool but it is only showing 'content js min.js:1'.

Please see this image http://myfilestore.tk/net/Capture.PNG?a=so14052013

Comment: You can try the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Possibly related: [Chrome Dev Tools: Tells me what type of event is attached to element but which file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881737/chrome-dev-tools-tells-me-what-type-of-event-is-attached-to-element-but-which-f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you want is to see the click event handlers registered for an element.

You can use event data to achieve this in the console, though you have to note that it is private method - not documented may get changed in future without any notification

Ex:

```
var clicks = jQuery._data( jQuery('element')[0] , "events" ).click;
```

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) also

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wjVjk/)

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Audit plugin](https://github.com/zertosh/jquery-audit) plugin should do the trick. It's not perfect, but it should give you what you want.